# Display uneven Trees with d3tree

Tags: r, d3tree

I have the following data that I read from csv file:

```
Level1,Level2,Level3,value
1,1.1,1.1.1,1.0
1,1.2,,1.1
1,1.3,1.3.1,1.0
2,2.1,,1.1
2,2.2,2.2.1,1.5
3,3.1,3.1.1,1.2
3,3.1,3.1.2,1.4
```

As you can see my tree depth varies for different branches. I use the code below to display the tree in R.

```
require(d3Tree)
TN<-as.data.frame(read.csv("nodes.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")) 
TNjson<-df2tree(rootname="root",TN,toolTip = TN$value)
d3tree(list(root=TNjson,layout="cartesian"))
```

The output displays as below. My question is how do I display this tree as intended, without empty leafs?

[image: d3Tree Output]

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `NA`s the empty strings when you read your file:

```
TN<-read.csv("nodes.csv", na.strings="")
```

No need to coerce to a `data.frame`, since `read.csv` already returns a `data.frame` and no need also to specify the `header` and the `sep`, which are the correct ones by default. On the other hand, you need to specify the values you want to be translated to `NA`s when reading the file, and in this case it's the empty string.